# How to reference the event context for events defined in a backbone.js view?

Tags: backbone.js, view, this

I have my view set up with some events and I want to reference, for example, the button element that was clicked because it has a data attribute I need.  I want to do it like so:

```
events: {
    'click #testGadget': 'fireEvent',
    ...
},
fireEvent:  function(){
    var x = $(this).data('iCanHaz')
}
```

But the 'this' variable is scoped to the view itself.  I know there's a way to accomplish what I'm looking to do but I can't seem to word my question in a way that returns any google hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can simply be done with the `event.target` property:

```
fireEvent:  function(e){
    var x = $(e.target).data('iCanHaz')
}
```

see [Event Object doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)